# Как сделать нумерацию пользователей в сообщении

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

Есть сообщение с топом пользователей по рейтингу, данные выводятся из `бд`, нужно всех пользователей пронумеровать, как это сделать - я не понимаю

```py
def top_rating(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute('SELECT user_id, game_nickname, rating FROM users order by rating desc limit 10')
    users = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()

    msg = "✨ Топ 10 рейтингов: \n\n"+"\n".join(f"[{user[1]}](tg://user?id={user[0]}) - {user[2]}⭐" for user in users)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=msg, parse_mode='Markdown', disable_web_page_preview=True)

    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), попробуйте так:

```
msg = "✨ Топ 10 рейтингов: \n\n"+"\n".join(f"{num}. [{user[1]}](tg://user?id={user[0]}) - {user[2]}⭐" for num, user in enumerate(users, start=1))
```